# How To Use SQL Profiler on Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, profiling

I’m trying to figure out how to use SQL Profiler for SQL Server 2012 to monitor queries executed on a trigger? When the update trigger fires for Table A, SQL Profiler would record the select statements for Table B, C. It would also record update statement for Table D and values being stored in the variables for the trigger in Table A. Based on this, can you advise how to setup SQL Profiler to log all of this information?

Comment: If you have variables in your trigger you very likely have something very wrong in your trigger. Scalar variables in a trigger a huge red flag that the trigger assumes only 1 row will ever be inserted/updated. The challenge you are experiencing is one of the many reasons that triggers are often not a good way to handle data. You can't see them in profiler, just like with a stored procedure. What shows up in profiler is the actual statement executed, not the contents of any triggers it may fire.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong term but this is what I referring as a variable as part of my trigger   

DECLARE @Price  Decimal(10,2)

Comment: No you are using the correct term. That variable declaration is a HUGE red flag that your trigger has problems. You have scalar variables in a trigger, your code needs to be set based. But as I said before, you can't see these values from a trigger in profiler. Just like you can't track every statement inside of a procedure from profiler.

Comment: I did thought of an solution to address my issue.  I will make a table that will insert the values I want to monitor and include a timestamp.

Comment: Yes. And do yourself a favor and make your trigger stop using scalar variables. You should be able to do everything set based using the inserted and deleted virtual tables.

Comment: This company had this trigger with scalar variables before I worked with them.  Because the application been dependent on this logic, it would be an investment of time to have it to work in another way.

Comment: I have known of two different companies that actually closed their doors because they had triggers like this. And once it was discovered how horrible the design was it was more investment than they could put together. Definitely can be a large piece of work but if there is actual business logic in these triggers then it is work that must be done because scalar triggers just don't work. When you see things like "Set @MyVar = SomeCol from inserted" you are in for a long ride. I wish you the best.